# Upgrade Kubuntu 20.04 LTS to Kubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu

I need to upgrade my Kubuntu 20.04 LTS to Kubuntu 22.04 LTS

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Test:

Update system:

```
  sudo apt update

  sudo apt upgrade
```

Run the update process:

```
  sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: I get this result:     ValueError: could not convert string to float: '6.06 LTS'
lsb_release returned exitcode: 1
There is no development version of an LTS available.
To upgrade to the latest non-LTS development release 
set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.

Comment: "set Prompt=normal" in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades. sudo nano /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades